# Playing an MP3 with LAME

Tags: c#, mp3, decode, lame

I'm looking into making a desktop music player, probably in C# (not certain yet), and for MP3 support I would like to use LAME for various quality and other reasons. I am used to coding in Java and as such have only used Java libraries with Java and don't quite understand how to use LAME to play an MP3 in my program.

I have used lame.exe on the command line to decode an MP3 to WAV (`lame.exe --decode "filename.mp3")`  but don't see how I can play an MP3 with LAME nor how to do it in a program (i.e. not using command line).

Do I have to be using C to use the LAME library?

Also do I have to decode the MP3 first before playing?

Comment: Isn't it inefficient to convert the whole mp3 to a wav before playing it, when you can stream the playing of an mp3 directly?